# How to connect with socket.io from a ws client?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I have a very simple socket.io chat example, and the server side code is like this:

https://github.com/js-demos/socketio-chat-demo/blob/master/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static('public'));

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

The client side using the socket io code to connect it and is working well:

https://github.com/js-demos/socketio-chat-demo/blob/master/public%2Findex.html

```
<script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
</script>
```

But I want to use some other websocket client to connect the server, say, `wscat`:

```
npm install -g wscat
wscat ws://localhost:3000
```

But it can't connect, with this error:

```
error: Error: socket hang up
```

Is my url `ws://localhost:3000` is wrong? How to make it work?

PS: You can see this project https://github.com/js-demos/socketio-chat-demo/ and try it

Answer (score 35):

From the Chrome Dev Tools, I found the real websocket url, it should be:

```
ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket
```

Use this url with wscat works well

Comment: This worked for me. How did you find this though/is there a reason why ws://localhost:3000 doesn't work?

Answer (score 14):

Agreeing with @freewind 's answer, I would like to go little deeper with the detail description.

```
ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket
```

The specification can be described as

```
+----------------+--------------------+
|      Elm       |        Desc        |
+----------------+--------------------+
| WS             | scheme             |
| localhost:3000 | host               |
| socket.io      | path               |
| EIO=3          | EngineIO version 3 |
| transport      | websocket          |
+----------------+--------------------+
```

If the transport is set to `websocket` then It can be testable with any WebSocket client as it's upgrading the connection with the WebSocket protocol.

We can easily test and debug it with the [Firecamp WebSocket Client](https://firecamp.io/websocket/). The connection will look like this below image.

### [Firecamp](https://firecamp.app) is the GUI client for the [SocketIO and WebSocket](https://firecamp.io/websocket/).

**1. SocketIO**

The configuration of the following screen will be like

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io( "http://localhost:3000/socket.io", 
 {
  "path": "/socketio",
  "transports": [
    "websocket"
  ]
 }
);
```

[image]

**2. WebSocket**

The same socket endpoint, We can test it with the WebSocket client as showing in following images

**- *WS* connection**
[image]

**- *WS* feed data**
[image]

Comment: How would I do this when it has been deployed to production on Elastic Beanstalk?  I replaced localhost with my server IP but I wasn't getting anything back but when I'm on localhost it works. @nishchit-dhanani

Comment: @NathanielBabalola It's strange. would you like to join Discord Server? we'll discuss there in depth. It might be a CORS issue at first glance. https://discord.gg/8hRaqhK

Comment: okay, just messaged you @nishchit-dhanani