# Socket.IO and express unable to connect

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to build a simple signaling server for WebRTC using Socket.IO and Express. I've never used Express or Socket.IO before so I figure I'd just run through a couple examples (using ES6). Not surprisingly, I'm running into trouble just connecting to the server. Can anyone advise? Here is my very basic server straight from the docs, modified to ES6 using https://github.com/riebel/socketio-es6-starter as a guide.

```
import http from 'http';
import express from 'express'
import SocketIO from 'socket.io'

let app = express();
let server = http.Server(app);
let io = new SocketIO(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.send('hi');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    "use strict";
   socket.emit('news', {hello: 'world'});
   socket.on('my other event', (data) => {
       console.log(data)
   })
});

server.listen(80, () => {
    "use strict";
    console.log('Listening on port 80');
});
```

I'm using the `wscat` utility from npm and every time I try to connect I just get this:
[image]

I've tried using the DEBUG environment variable but it doesn't seem to do much. I also tried doing ws://localhost:80/socket.io as per that last line but it didn't work:
[image]

Comment: socket.io is an additional layer on top of webSocket.  You can't connect webSocket -> socket.io or vice versa.  You need a socket.io client to connect to a socket.io server.

Answer (score 0):

Alright it seems like the socket connection is a little more involved than I thought when using Socket.IO. There is actually nothing wrong with the server as above, but simply using `wscat` and trying to connect to only `ws://localhost` is incorrect. I think it would work for just WebSockets but if you're using Socket.IO it is different. The full command in Windows shell to connect with my set-up using the `wscat` utility (in my case) must be

```
wscat -c ws://localhost:80/socket.io/\?transport=websocket
```

Note the endpoint is`/socket.io/`. You can also use this URL from here [How to connect with socket.io from a ws client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642525/how-to-connect-with-socket-io-from-a-ws-client) (careful with the escaping):

```
ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket
```

And you can also try the `iocat` npm package which seems to simplify it like I was trying to do in the first place.