# Connect to a socket.io server from a Node.js server using the 'ws' package

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a Node.js server which utilizes the popular `ws` package for using web sockets. I'd like to use this library to connect to an third party server which is running socket.io.

If I were to use socket.io on my server, the connection code would be something like this:

```
const socket = socketIo('https://api.example.com/1.0/scores')
```

I've attempted to connect to the same service using the `ws` package, and modifying the url:

```
const wsClient = new WebSocket('wss://api.example.com/1.0/scores');
```

but this results in the following:

> Error: Unexpected server response: 200

**Question:**
What needs to be done to connect to a third party server running socket.io from a server running the `ws` package?

**Additional Info:**

- I've noticed in my searches that some people have suggested appending
  `/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket` to the end of the url. This
  does not throw the same error as above (`> Error: Unexpected server
  response: 200`) nor throw any visible error, but does not appear to
  work (no data is received from the remote server).
- Using `new WebSocket('ws://api.example.com/1.0/scores?EIO=3&transport=websocket');` to open the connection (via `ws`) results in the following stack trace:

  ```
  { Error: Parse Error
      at Socket.socketOnData 
      at emitOne 
      at Socket.emit 
      // ... 
  }
  ```

Comment: Run your server code with `NODE_DEBUG=net,https,socket*,ws* node server.js` and post the logs when the connection happens. This issue is mostly related to the handshake not being handled properly by the 3rd party server server

Comment: @TarunLalwani Logs: https://gist.github.com/Orbyt/12368837372fb7dd3a8f69e3ec0e521b

Comment: Doesn't give much info. Is your project open source or something?

Comment: @TarunLalwaniI It's not, but the server code is very small. Additionally, I do not have access to the source code of the third party server.

Comment: Is the third party link shareable? Without some additional logs its tough to say what next

Comment: `?EIO=3&transport=websocket` works for me. Try to send some request to server or try to emit something from server

Comment: This question has been answered before:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642525/how-to-connect-with-socket-io-from-a-ws-client

Comment: Try just appending the suggested query (and not modifying the path), i.e. if the original URL is `'ws://api.example.com/1.0/scores'` then try `ws://api.example.com/1.0/scores?EIO=3&transport=websocket`

Comment: I noticed you were using wss:// when creating the websocket, try ws:// as shown in the example using EIO=3&tarnsport=websocket

Comment: @bgran @Jordan I've attempted to removing the additional portion from the path (i.e. `ws://api.example.com/1.0/scores?EIO=3&transport=websocket`) and received an `{ Error: Parse Error at Socket.socketOnData ... }`. I will append this to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Because Socket.IO doesn't guarantee that there will be a WebSockets server hosted like you're seeming to expect, you should instead use their standard client package.

```
npm i socket.io-client
```

Then use the package in your code:

```
const ioClient = require('socket.io-client')('https://example.com/1.0/scores')
```

The full docs for socket.io-client are available on their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client).

**Note**: Honestly, though, it's just better at this point to use WebSockets instead if possible. WebSockets has become well-supported in browsers and is quite standard. Socket.IO is rarely necessary and could add some overhead.

Comment: My server is already utilizing the `ws` package. The question is about connecting to a third party server that is already using socket.io. I've edited the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @Orbit Ok, so I see what you're trying to do and using just websockets to connect is not really following conventions and could break down the road. I strongly recommend that you use the official socket.io-client package (like in my answer) to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, using the official socket.io client works as expected, but that is not what the question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

The socket.io api utilizes websockets but it also has a lot of other functions built on top of it in order to do things such as HTTP handshakes, session ids, and it can even handle fail overs to other protocols when needed.

You got half of the issue so far. Adding the line `socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket` you're specifying parameters for the socket.io server to take.

`EIO=3` specifies the version number for engine.io in which socket.io is using. In this case you are saying engine.io version = 3

`transport=websocket` specifies which transport protocol to use. As i said earlier, socket.io uses other protocols in cases such as fail overs. This portion forces socket.io to use websocket as the preferred protocol.

Now the next half is the WebSocket. WebSocket allows for Extensions which includes different kinds of compression that are commonly used when sending data. Which I believe is what is causing your `Parse Error`

Try this ([found here](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/243)):

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://server/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket', {
   perMessageDeflate: false
});
```

By setting perMessageDeflate: false you are specifying "Do not compress data". Since as i said this is a WebSocket Extension there are different variations as well. Try these instead if it doesn't work

- x-webkit-deflate-frame
- perframe-deflate

As a disclaimer this information is from the research that I have done. Im not a "socket.io specialist" so if there's anything incorrect please comment and i'll edit the post.