# URL generated by SocketIO in NodeJS running locally

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm using Socket.IO to run a WebSocket server locally in NodeJS using the following code:

```
import express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
import http = require('http');
import { Socket } from 'socket.io';


const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const socketio = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Node Server is running");
});

server.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

socketio.on("connection", (socket: Socket) => {
  console.log(`connect ${socket.id}`);
  console.log(`connect ${socket.handshake.url}`);

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(`disconnect ${socket.id}`);
  });
});
```

Using a tool like [Firecamp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firecamp-a-campsite-for-d/eajaahbjpnhghjcdaclbkeamlkepinbl?hl=en), I try to establish a connection on `ws://localhost:3000`, but to no avail. I eventually use the Socket.IO client to connect from a simple web page by running `let socket = io()`. It seems the only reason this works is because that call connects to the host serving the page by default, as stated [here](https://socket.io/get-started/chat). Running `console.log(socket)` and looking at the output, I eventually find that the URL inside the **engine** field is `ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=qerg3iHm3IKMOjdNAAAA`.
My question is why is the URL so complicated rather than simply `ws://localhost:3000`? And is there no easier way to get the URL instead of having to access it through dev tools?

Comment: I've explained this answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/53893747/2837412

Answer (score 1):

A socket.io server does not accept generic webSocket connections.  It only accepts socket.io connections as socket.io goes through an extra layer of preparation stuff (over http) before establishing the actual webSocket connection.  It then also adds a layer on top of the regular webSocket packet format to support some of its features (such as message names).

When using a socket client to connect to a socket.io server in the default configuration, socket.io first makes a few regular http requests to the socket.io server and with those http requests it sends a few parameters.  In your URL:

```
 ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=qerg3iHm3IKMOjdNAAAA
```

The path:

```
/socket.io/
```

Is the path that the socket.io server is looking for requests on as destined for the socket.io server.  Since this is a unique path and not generally used by other requests, this allows you to share an http server between socket.io and other http requests.  In fact, this is a common way to deploy a socket.io server (hooking into an http server that you are already using for http requests).

In fact, the path `/socket.io/socket.io.js` is also served by the socket.io server and that will return the client-side `socket.io.js` file.  So, clients often use this in their HTML files:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

as a means of getting the socket.io client code.  Again you see the use of the path prefix `/socket.io` on all socket.io related URLs.

In your original URL, you can see parameters for:

```
EIO=4                      // engine.io protocol version
transport=websocket        // desired transport once both sides agree
sid=qerg3iHm3IKMOjdNAAAA   // client identifier so the server knows which client this
                           // is before the actual webSocket connection is established
```

Once both sides agree that the connection looks OK, then the client will make a webSocket connection to the server.  In cases where webSocket connections are blocked (by network equipment that doesn't support them or blocks them), then socket.io will use a form of http polling where it repeatedly "polls" the server asking for any more data and it will attempt to simulate a continuous connection.  The client configuration can avoid this http polling and go straight to a webSocket connection if you want, but you would give up the fallback behavior in case continuous webSocket connections are blocked.

> And is there no easier way to get the URL instead of having to access it through dev tools?

Not really.  This URL is not something you have to know at all.  The socket.io client will construct this URL for you.  You just specify `http://localhost:3000` as the URL you want to connect to and the socket.io client will add the other parameters to it.

Comment: @omarsharaki - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.