# Can't make a simple socket.io work ( even though equivalent Websocket code works )

Tags: websocket, socket.io

Codes based from https://github.com/fireship-io/socketio-minimal-demo/blob/main/server/index.js

Only Version 1 (Websocket version) below works:

```
wscat -c "ws://localhost:8282"

Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
> s
< Roger that! s
> f
< Roger that! f
```

Version 2 & 3 (socket.io version) returns `socket hang-up`:

```
wscat -c "ws://localhost:8282"
error: socket hang up
```

---

Version 1: Websocket

```
// server.js

const WebSocket = require('ws')
const server = new WebSocket.Server({ port: '8282' })

server.on('connection', socket => { 

  socket.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message)
    socket.send(`Roger that! ${message}`);

  });

});
```

Version 2: socket.io+http

```
// server.js

const http = require('http').createServer();

const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    cors: { origin: "*" }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('message', (message) =>     {
        console.log(message);
        io.emit('message', `${socket.id.substr(0,2)} said ${message}` );   
    });
});

http.listen(8282, () => console.log('listening on http://localhost:8282') );
```

Version 3: socket.io only

```
// server.js

const options = { /* ... */ };
const io = require("socket.io")(options);
// const io = require("socket.io");

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('message', (message) =>     {
        console.log(message);
        // io.emit('message', `${socket.id.substr(0,2)} said ${message}` );   
    });
});

io.listen(8282);
```

I run the backend using `node server.js`

I have also tested the response using `Simple Websocket Client` extension on chrome I get the same behavior when I test using `wscat` in the terminal.

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642525/how-to-connect-with-socket-io-from-a-ws-client

Comment: Thanks, it worked, though I have to use EIO=4 instead of EIO=3. The fix was simple after I checked the url+params the socket.io client is using to connect to the server (visible at chrome devtools).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tip from Mehmet, I checked the url+params at the dev tools network tab and made it work.

```
wscat -c "ws://localhost:8282/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket"
Connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
< 0{"sid":"sSYAv_rKLATxmMEGAAAT","upgrades":[],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000}
< 2
Disconnected (code: 1005, reason: "")
```

It seems everything should be already working anyway if only I use the socket.io-client js lib to connect (while on html+javascript).

When I used command-line wscat, I did not know that there should be parameters in the url when using socket.io

The fix was simple after I checked the url+params the socket.io client is using to connect to the server (visible at chrome devtools network tab).

Comment: Yep, I forgot to add socket.io to end of the url. I was merely trying to debug a socket.io connection with postman. I prob shoulda used ws package but your answer works also, thanks